# Is HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context unique for each request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httpcontext

In MVC3, I want to access the `HttpContext` from a Controller (not the `HttpContextBase` returned by the `HttpContext` property). Several articles (and StackOverflow answers) suggest using `HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context`. I've tried it, and it works, simple enough.

Can someone confirm that this property is unique per request and thread safe? Maybe it's just me, but I find the name `ApplicationInstance` confusing - it denotes an application-scope value (i.e., not unique per request).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did a quick google on `HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context` and found the following article at MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.applicationinstance.aspx

which states:

> Gets or sets the HttpApplication object for the ***current*** HTTP request.